# Grep php file to show if any matches to certain keywords

Tags: grep

Ok so I am trying to look of malicious code on server but am getting nowhere fast :)

This is what I have

```
<?php
$command = "grep --file=list.txt ./*";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "$output";
echo "Grep job over.";
?>
```

list.txt - contains... (one string per line)

```
eval(base64_decode(
gzinflate(base64_decode(
cwd = @getcwd();
chr((ord(
substr(md5(strrev(
chr(ord(
cwd[strlen(\$cwd)
ini_get('safe_mode');
=\"\x62\"
\"+ r + \"&r=\" + document.referrer;\"
if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) ) == \"WIN\")
window.top.location.href=\"http://
@ini_get(\"disable_functions\")
){if(@copy(
eval(\$___(\$__));
copy(\"endless.html\"
system(\"wget
symlink(\"/\",\"sym/root\");
@copy(\$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
error_reporting(0);if(
x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74
hacked"
```

Would be very grateful if someone can explain where have gone wrong

Comment: Are the `*.log` files in the same directory as the script?

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes in regular expressions.

Comment: I just added a .log file on the route folder same folder as grabfile.php ?!? - i have grabfile.php, list.txt and .log in route folder

Comment: have now added ./* instead of .log but still not working ?

Comment: Try using absolute pathnames. I'm not sure what the working directory is when PHP scripts are run from the webserver.

Comment: not sure if i am making it worse or getting closer to what is needed but tried this                
$command = "grep -ri '--file=public_html/list.txt' ./*";

Comment: Try `--file=public_html/list.txt public_html/*.log`

Comment: no this doesnt work either

Comment: Then use an absolute pathname, like I suggested earlier. An absolute path starts with `/` and specifies the entire path from the root directory, e.g. `/var/www/public_html/list.txt` The actual path will depend on how your server is configured.